# jQueryMobile Tap to Stop Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I'm using *jQuery Mobile* to build a cross platform mobile app and I have the following issue:

Whenever there is a list with many items, the user scrolls down and when taps to stop the scrolling, the item gets clicked instead of stopping the scroll, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I solved it by creating a flag variable that gets turned off on the stopscroll jqm event.

```
var tapFlag = true;
$(document).on("scrollstart",function(){
    tapFlag = false;
});
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
    tapFlag = true;
});
```

and only allow the items to be tapped if the tap flag is true.